# How to save a qgis graph to a shapefile to use in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, gis, networkx, qgis

I created a graph from a layer using the code below. I want to save this graph to a shapefile for further use in networkx.
I don't want to also save it as a QGIS layer. So how can I simply save it without giving a layer as the first argument of writeAsVectorFormat?
And if I try give an existing layer as argument it gives a strange bug: the code runs, and Windows shows the .shp file at the recent files in Windows Explorer, but when I want to open it it says that the file does not exist, and I also can't see it in the folder where it should be.
I also can't find how to just create a random layer, so if it's really needed to create a layer, can someone tell me how to do it?

Thank you for help

```
from qgis.analysis import *

vectorLayer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()

director = QgsVectorLayerDirector(vectorLayer, 12, '2.0', '3.0', '1.0', QgsVectorLayerDirector.DirectionBoth)

# The index of the field that contains information about the edge speed
attributeId = 1
# Default speed value
defaultValue = 50
# Conversion from speed to metric units ('1' means no conversion)
toMetricFactor = 1
strategy = QgsNetworkSpeedStrategy(attributeId, defaultValue, toMetricFactor)

director.addStrategy(strategy)

builder = QgsGraphBuilder(vectorLayer.crs())

startPoint = QgsPointXY(16.8346339,46.8931070)
endPoint = QgsPointXY(16.8376039,46.8971058)

tiedPoints = director.makeGraph(builder, [startPoint, endPoint])

graph = builder.graph()

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "temp", "memory")

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(v1, "zzsh.shp", "CP1250", vectorLayer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")

#QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ZZMap07 copy')[0]
```

Comment: Save the file in a known location and open it from there. Are you sure that in recent file you have the file you downloaded (and not a old one)? Check the modification date. And browser may download and move files.

Comment: It's like it shows up for a moment so recent file recognizes it, but it "vanishes" instantly.
I try to give an exact path for saving, but with an other script this method of saving file worked and the file showed up at the project root.

Comment: More important question is:
Can someone help me how to create a layer (with scipt) to save the graph to? As writeAsVectorFormat asks for a layer as the first argument.

Comment: Recent files is not a folder, it is just a "dynamic collection". You should check where the file are saved. You have control (and data) in the browser you used. Possibly it is in "Downloads" (default, but you never know, check the setting of the browser, or ask to browser to open the location of downloaded file, so you will know where it saves them). The second question may seem a usage question. Ask to our GIS sister site (links on the top right icon, then "all sites")

Comment: I know that recent files is not a folder, I clicked on "open containing folder"

Comment: I created a layer just for this case, and gave it as an argument to writeAsVectorFormat. I also gave the function a path this way: 
myDir = 'C:/Shapefiles/'

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('zzshlayer')[0], myDir + "zzsh.shp", "utf-8", vectorLayer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile")

Now it runs, but I think the shapefile is empty.

Comment: I realized that I didn't even add the graph as an input for writeAsVectorFormat function. I have to add it first to a layer. 
How to add a qgisgraph to a new layer in python?